# Increase the battery life of a laptop

Tags: laptop

I am a developer who uses Visual studio 2008 C# for my works. I am using my own laptop for my work.

What is the proper power options that I can use to increase the battery life of laptop ?

The laptop is on and working for over 15 hours a day, so taking the proper power option is important.

Comment: Tiva, you might get a better response on SuperUser, as this is more a general computer question instead of a programming one.

Comment: you should ask your question on superuser , as much as it's related to programming, it really is not a programming question

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of battery life extension tips articles if you'll search. [The first result](http://www.friedbeef.com/top-15-ways-to-extend-your-laptop-battery-life/) on my search was one of the more comprehensive and concise guides.

I'll summarise what seem to be the most repeated points:

- **Use your resources as lightly and efficiently as possible.** Everything comes back to this point.
- Turn the screen brightness down.
- Don't run resource-heavy programs, don't run virus-scans and run as few programs as you can at a time (meaning you might want to shut down some taskbar apps). If you use Windows Vista, disabling Windows 3D Aero might take a chip off your total resource consumption.
- Minimise your usage of the CD/DVD drive, Wireless card and external devices. If you have an external hard drive, copy the files you want to use onto your local hard drive first.
- More RAM and regular defragging both decrease the demand on your hard drive.
- Utilise Power Options in your Control Panel to keep system resources in check.
- Like Kara said, keep heat low so as to keep the system running at peak efficiency.

If you live in a hot climate like myself, I'll throw this in: A friend of mine had significant heat problems cooling pads weren't solving. One miniature 5" fan pointed at his laptop's exhaust vent worked wonders.

Answer (score 3):

The big concern for laptops (especially those churning through heavy graphics or compiling operations) is **HEAT**.  Do whatever you can do reduce how hot the laptop gets, and you'll reduce the majority of the problems.  Here are a few suggestions.

- if you don't need the battery, take it out while using the laptop.  Just having it connected while the laptop is on generates and traps a ton of heat.
- Become aware of the fans, vents, and intakes.  Make sure they're never obstructed, and always have access to cool air.  Check them regularly (if possible) for dust/fur and clean/vacuum them if you can.
- Install a temperature monitoring app, possibly with a desktop widget, to be aware of the current temperature of whatever sensors your laptop has.
- Don't strain your eyes, but lowering the screen brightness reduces power draw
- Really, any tip that makes the battery last longer will lower the power draw & therefore heat generation of your laptop.  There are tons of laptop-battery-life extending tips here on SU.