# How can I increase my laptop battery life?

Tags: hardware-failure, battery, battery-life

I don't have enough knowledge about laptop care. I have a second hand hp laptop core i5 . Last two weeks I notice that the battery of my laptop low very soon specially during audio and video use. How can I manage my laptop battery life ?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/200031/increase-the-battery-life-of-a-laptop#200114

Comment: Buy a new battery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase the battery life of a laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/200031/increase-the-battery-life-of-a-laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your battery is simply dying and needs to be replaced.

That said, if this happened fairly suddenly and without a change in use profile (as might be inferred from your question), then the issue is likely that something is draining the battery.   If this is the case there will be other signs - like your laptop is always warm/hot.   TO address both this specific issue and the more general one of extending battery lif - look at your task manager to see what is using the CPU and if its not needed, kill it, and make sure it stays dead.

You can probably also tell by looking at the health of the battery.  You have not specified your OS (but look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154554/how-do-i-get-battery-information-in-windows) link) - but on many (most?) batteries from decent providers you can also check how your battery compares to new, and a whole lot of other information.   If the maximum full charge is < 80% of original full charge, industry says the battery should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems like a duplicate of [Increase the battery life of a laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/200031/increase-the-battery-life-of-a-laptop), but whatever. You can decrease the screen brightness for a big boost in battery life. Also be sure to close out of programs when you are done with them. When an application uses the cpu a lot, and it gets left open, it will surely kill your battery life.

Answer (score 0):

There are several means to do so. Screen brightness as told before is a big point.

You can also tweak with energy saving features available with your OS, those are in battery/power profiles, and you'll want to reduce CPU frequency to improve autonomy. The downside of that is possible decrease of performance.

You can also set your hard drives (if mechanicals) to pause if not used, though in the long run it will shorten their span. On average, where an i5 would use 100Wh, a hard drive uses 10Wh, approx.

GPUs can be tweaked, either it is the integrate graphics of your CPU or a dedicated PCI-Express chipset, you could find settings to lower things such as the power consumption or the refresh rate. Decreased performance is possible.

You should unplug every unnecessary device from your laptop.

In the long term though it is believed that maintaining your battery around 50% would increase its lifespan. I haven't verified that myself as it would require two identical devices with similar usage which is a bit absurd for an average consumer. But you could try that, though you may not have the opportunity to make proper use of your computer with only half battery.

Should you want to apply any of these solutions, googling such keywords should lead you to tutorials to how to do that : Power management (your OS name) (your CPU)| (your GPU)